# Yii2 - I have a form that I want to use in various actions, but i dont want to intiazlie this forn to each action

Tags: yii2

Yii2- I have a form that I want to use in various actions, but i don't want to initialize this form to each action.

For example: To use Login form in a Modal.

Comment: Was this an FYI, or did you have a question?

Comment: I would recommend you elaborate